# How can I produce rows that sum subgroups of rows, without grouping?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
ID    Income    Expenses
-------------------------
1     $1000      $200
1     $2000      $400
2     $500       $200
2     $100       $60
```

I'd like to add one **row** per ID that sums the ID's Income and Expenses. For example:

```
ID    Income    Expenses
-------------------------
1-SUM $3000      $600
1     $1000      $200
1     $2000      $400
2-SUM $600       $260
2     $500       $200
2     $100       $60
```

**Is this possible with SQL?** I read about OVER and PARTITION BY but that'll add a new column, not a new row. **Might a UNION be the best way to go here?**

Comment: These '1-SUM' and '2-SUM' is what you want in this row or just it indicates that it is sum???

Comment: I'm looking for a column to be added/changed to distinguish grouped rows from non-grouped rows.

Comment: Added  Group Level Indicator. I think you should allow `GROUP BY` answers, your title excludes such beautiful solution ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx):

**[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f4b4/9)**

```
CREATE TABLE tab(id INT , income INT , expenses INT);

INSERT INTO tab(id, income, expenses)
VALUES (1, 1000, 200),(1, 2000, 400),(2, 500, 200),(2, 100, 60)


SELECT id,
       [income]         = SUM(income),
       [expenses]       = SUM(expenses),
       [grouping_level] = GROUPING_ID(id, income, expenses) /* 0 - actual data , 3 - group based on column income, expenses*/
FROM tab
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((id), (id,income, expenses))
```

Why grouping is useful:

- Using `GROUPING SETS` gives great flexibility for instance when you want total sum use: `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((id), (id,income, expenses), ())`
- `GROUPING SETS` can be combined with `ROLLUP/CUBE`.
- `GROUPING_ID` indicates grouping level.
  Number works like binary. `GROUPING(a, b, c)` if b i c is used for grouping you get 011B => 3

Comment: I like the use of GROUPING SETS but how can I alter the id for rows that represented grouped data or add a column to the indicate which rows are grouped? Even a NULL ID for grouped rows might be sufficient.

Comment: Would adding GROUPING_ID(id, income, expenses) in the SELECT allow me to identify grouped rows?

Comment: @Craig, Yes you can use `GROUPING_ID` to determine grouped rows also you can filter using `GROUPING_ID` in `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
   create table yourtable(id int,income int,expenses int)
   insert into yourtable values (1,100,200),(1,150,250),(2,200,300),(2,250,350)

    with CTE
    as
    (select ID,sum(income) as income,sum(expenses) as expenses,1 as isSum 
      from yourtable 
      group by id
    )

    select * from (
    select *,0 as isSum from yourtable
    union all
    select * from  CTE ) as t
    order by id,issum
```

output
[image: Output]

Comment: If I have to group on more levels and there will be more columns this quickly grows and won't be readable.